# how to send message to a specific user by username at any application point

Tags: spring, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket, messagebroker

I am implementing spring boot stomp message broker socket to interact with webclient. i need to send sms to  a specific user by username at some application point,means the message will be trigger from server to client. client will subscribe to a topic/queue. i heard @SendtoUser send sms to the perticular user, but here in my case user is just subscribing a topic, then from backend i need to send sms time to time to specific user. user will not send any sms to server.
its just push based sms.

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId,"/queue/something", payload, 
    headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
```

but here from where will i get the session id for the targeted user. here user is just subscribing the topic once.

Comment: I think client should subscribe websocket server by username or hash-username that already stored in database and then server can find username from database for send sms to particular user as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find answer to a similar question (with project exemple) here :
[Spring websocket send to specific people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198292/spring-websocket-send-to-specific-people/43224705#43224705)

The fact that user is subscribing once is not a problem. One the connection is established, the server can send has much message as needed.

Comment: stompClient.subscribe('/topic/connect/'+theUserId, function (data)                   {
//Handle data
              } 
        }); here if a user subscribe with some other user name other's sms will go to the user. how to make a secutity check

Comment: can i make a authentication on subscription

Comment: Yes, you must prevent users to suscribe on another user's channel. It's possible but I don't remember how.